# How does one use mysqlimport with reserved-word table name?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

A third party has provided a table in CSV format that is named, "KEY.txt". When using `mysqlimport` to import the file, the following error is returned:

```
$ mysqlimport fooDB KEY.txt
mysqlimport: Error: 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'KEY' at line 1, when using table: KEY
```

Of course, using reserved words as table and column names is a Bad Idea™. One solution would be to simply rename the file to a non-reserved word, but this is not ideal.

However, MySQL *does* support using reserved words, as long as the table or column name is put in backtick quotes. The following query from within the mysql client works:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'KEY.txt" INTO TABLE `KEY`;
Records: 303  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Is there a way to get `mysqlimport` to backtick-quote the table name?

Comment: According to comments in [bug 48126](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48126) this was fixed circa MySQL 5.7. What version are you using?

Comment: You should not use keywords as table name

Comment: I checked the source code from the MySQL 5.5 branch. I confirmed [mysqlimport delimits table names with back-ticks](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.5/client/mysqlimport.c#L350-L358). Older branches aren't in the github repo, so I haven't confirmed which older versions also work correctly.

Comment: I just did a quick test of import to a table named `key` on my local MySQL instance, which is 8.0.31. It works without error.

Comment: Can you answer the question of what version you are using? I.e. what is returned by `SELECT VERSION();`?

Comment: @BillKarwin Good catch on the bug - it didn't come up in any of my searches.

The client version is `mysqlimport  Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))` (WSL) and the server is `8.0.18`. The query is not showing in the general log, and `--verbose` doesn't report the query being executed.

The code you highlighted seems to only escape existing backticks with a second backtick; it doesn't appear to *add* backticks to the table name.

Comment: @BillKarwin `delete` was specified in `my.cnf` in `[mysqlimport]`, and turns out to be the culprit for the error. Looks like they're escaping the table name on the import statement, but not on the delete.

Comment: I've reported this as a bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109712. Feel free to click the "affects me" button on the bug screen.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks, but I beat you to it: https://bugs.mysql.com/109711 ;)

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing (v8.0.31 client, v8.0.18 server) `mysqlimport` does indeed properly handle reserved-word table names as expected, as long as the `--delete` option isn't specified (as an argument, or in `my.cnf`).